# mySQL VARCHAR(256) + mySQL INT = how many bytes?

Tags: mysql, database, int, varchar, utf-16

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `utftest`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf16;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `metadata_labels` (`metadata_id` INT NOT NULL , `label` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL ,  PRIMARY KEY (`metadata_id`, `label`));
```

however I get the following error msg:

```
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Please advise

Comment: Just tested this and it seems to work fine?

Comment: If possible, you should use an auto incrementing integer or GUID instead of a very long varchar as primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF 16 uses [32 bits per character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf16.html) (4 bytes) in MySQL. *4 x 256 > 767*.

If possible, I would recommend using something other than UTF16 `VARCHAR` for your key.

Comment: so what are options? i need to use UTF to support international characters and special characters.......

Comment: Is this required for the key?

Comment: yea, we need to support international characters in the metadata_labels.label

Answer (score 1):

In UTF8, it would require `3 x 256 + 4 = 772` bytes. UTF16 would take another 25% more.

You shouldn't use a primary key that's so wide; for an index to be efficient, the storage for each index should be kept to a minimum.

If you need to prevent duplicates, I would recommend adding a calculated field that contains a hash of the contents (e.g. sha1) and create a unique constraint on that instead.

Alternatively, use `latin1` as the character encoding for the `label` field to reduce the number of bytes to `256 + 4 = 300`.

If Unicode is a must and hashes are out of the picture you should reduce the column to either UTF8 (250 chars) or UTF16 (190 chars)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary utf8 may require between 1 and 3 bytes of storage for each character.

Comment: is there is a way where i don't have to add another field(hash)?

Comment: @SaqibAli You could try to reduce the field width down to 250.

Comment: The question references `utf16` which is 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @Jack. I have done that for now. But we will need to figure out a better DB schema